# The sum of all the elements in an Array

Tags: javascript

i am trying to do some examples.
i want to sum all the elements of the array
here is my code

```
var marks = [10, 20, 30, 40];
var total = 0;

for (var singleMark in marks) {
    total += marks;

}
console.log("the total marks re " + total);
```

But the results displayed is
**the total marks re 010,20,30,4010,20,30,4010,20,30,4010,20,30,40**

Please help me and tell me where am i doing it wrong.Thanks.
I can take the for loop but i want to learn using **foreach** as in **Javascript the definite guide book it says so**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For in will go over properties of objects. If you where to use for in on an array it will return you the index it is iterating over.

You should be using `forEach` to iterate over arrays.

```
marks.forEach(function(element, index){
    total+=element;
});
```

The element value is the `element` from the array, while the `index` value is the index that forEach is currently at. `index` is optional and does not need to be included.

Comment: `reduce` is better suited

Comment: @Max is this style of for each is better than my style?

Comment: @Max the element you set is given the value by default.?

Comment: It's not about style(even though it does look pretty), yet rather about the code you are using. for in will not get you the elements from the array directly. Next question: It's something called a callback. The value is already determined for you by javascript. The `index` will give you the number it is iterating over, however it is optional. You could just leave it as `function(element) { }`

Answer (score 5):

try like this

```
var marks = [10, 20, 30, 40];
var sum=marks.reduce(function(a, b){return a+b;})
```

From **@thomas** comment

ES6 syntax you can also write:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40].reduce((a,b) => a + b)
```

Comment: Will you min explaining what `reduce` does ? Your answer is spot on but it lacks explanation..

Comment: I agree with the previous comment.   `.reduce()` is made for this type of operation, but an answer with no explanation is never as good as it can be.

Comment: in ES6 syntax you can also write: `[10, 20, 30, 40].reduce((a,b) => a + b);`

Answer (score 2):

> Why don't you use conventional for loop ?

```
var marks = [10, 20, 30, 40];
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0, iLen = marks.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    total += marks[i];
}
console.log("the total marks re " + total);
```

> You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) too. The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

```
var total = [0, 1, 2, 3].reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
});
// total == 6
```

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini, Because it will calculate the `length` on every iteration. `iLen` will be used as a length returned by `.length`

Comment: wtf. Why are you using `var  i`, but aren't using `var iLen`?

Comment: @MaxMastalerz, I have used `,` not `;` and as per my knowledge, you can declare group of variables using `,` like `var foo = 'bar', bar = 'foo';` which is equivalent to `var foo = 'bar';var bar = 'foo';` Now will you tell me why did you use **wtf**???

Comment: Yes you have a point, however it comes down to making things understandable. Typically In javascript variables without var symbolize a global. It would be nice to differentiate them. Just my humble opinion.

Comment: @MaxMastalerz, In for loop you have 3 parts `INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; AFTERTHOUGHT`. Using `var iLen` in initialization will throw syntax error.  And using `marks.length` in CONDITION will cost you some CPU cycles...

Comment: @MaxMastalerz - the technique Rayon used with `iLen` is a very common speed optimization for a `for` loop and the way it is declared here is the usual way of doing it.  It's just like `var x, y, z;` declares three variables in the local scope.

Comment: alright I completely agree now. That is, if you care about performance on such a small data set. Also. I am aware of how for loops work :P

Comment: @MaxMastalerz, I'm glad to hear that..I reckon small data set is usually provided for demonstration purpose. By the way, will you tell me why did you use **wtf**???

Comment: wtf stands for `why the for` loop. Haha sorry.

Comment: As you said in the comment, **It would be nice to differentiate them**

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `for .. in` for traversing in array.
Use `for(..;..;..)`

The values are represented as strings in this way.

For reference, safer way:

```
for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
    sum += arr[i];
}
```

Comment: @MaxMastalerz, **JUSTIFY**

Comment: @MaxMastalerz each function has its own unique use, we have all the resources but use the best resource :)

Comment: @Please tell me how to add using forEach Loop

Comment: @RayonDabre Douglas crockford is Mr. JS GOD. Listen to him.  https://youtu.be/bo36MrBfTk4?t=21m28s

Comment: @MaxMastalerz, As per the syntax is concerned, `for-loop` is complex than `forEach` but it is not bad at all..With all due respect to **Douglas Crockford**

Comment: I completely agree it's not bad. In fact it's usually more efficient. But I personally prefer nice code over something weird looking. The only time I would use the regular for loop iteration is for a very large data set.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use the following two ways

var marks = [10, 20, 30, 40];
        var total = 0;
        marks.forEach(function addNumbers(value) {
            total += value;
        });
        console.log(total);

or
var marks = [10, 20, 30, 40];
        var total = 0;
        var singleMark;
        for (var i = 0; i < marks.length;i++) {
            total = total + marks[i];

        }
        console.log("the total marks re " + total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more high-order and readable approach:

    `marks.reduce(Math.sum, 0);`

The *reduce* function is used along with the Math.sum and does this: foreach element of marks, use `math.sum(cur, marks[i]);` to take the current element and the next one; do this until all of the elements in the array have been passed to the sum function and have been added up like this. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're just using the wrong variable `marks` instead of `singleMark` in your loop. Try this:

```
for (var singleMark in marks) {
    total += marks[singleMark];
}
```

Edit: However it is bad practice to use `in` to iterate through arrays. Consider using javascript [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) functions like `.reduce()` or `.forEach()`

Comment: your answer is displaying  the total marks re 00123

Comment: You can try simple casting by using `+`. Please see edit

Comment: No idea why my answer is getting down-voted :/
The key contribution of my answer is pointing out the apparent typo in OP's code.

Comment: `singleMark` is the index into the array, not the value of the array element which would be `marks[singleMark]`.  This code does not sum the elements of the array.

Comment: What is should say is: `total+=marks[singleMark]`, but it doesn't. Also mixing code meant for object iteration with array stuff is ugly.

Comment: @MaxMastalerz
ahhh good catch, created a typo myself when correct OP's :P

Comment: Still a BAD idea to ***ever*** use `in` to iterate contents of an array because it also iterates enumerable array properties.  ES6 added `of` just for this because `in` is such a bad choice.  `.reduce()` is likely the best choice.

Comment: @jfriend00
Agreed; Should stick with Array specific functions to avoid buggy iterations through unwanted elements

Answer (score 0):

Its Easy.

Create a function with a parameter.

Inside the function loop through the array Till the loop is finished.

Inside the Loop add the elements.

```
function sumArray(arra){

    var sum=0;
    for (var i = 0; i <arra.length; i++) {
        sum= sum+arra[i];
    }
}
```